# Help using preg_match for phone numbers

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, pcre

how would i write an if statement that would find phone numbers and store them to a variable. Here is what i have so far but its not working.

```
if (preg_match('/^(?:(?:\+?1\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?(?:\(\s*([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9])\s*\)|([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-8]1|[2-9][02-8][02-9]))\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?)?([2-9]1[02-9]|[2-9][02-9]1|[2-9][02-9]{2})\s*(?:[.-]\s*)?([0-9]{4})(?:\s*(?:#|x\.?|ext\.?|extension)\s*(\d+))?$
/', $buffer, $matches))
{
    $phonenumber = html_entity_decode($matches[1]);         
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some examples of phone numbers you want to match, and numbers you don't want to match? Or at least some more detailed requirements?

Comment: Can you explain in what way it's not working? Can you give an example where it fails, what output it gives, and what you expected?

Comment: This. Is a perfect "two problems" example.

Comment: It needs to match 3334445555, 333.444.5555, 333-444-5555, 333 444 5555, (333) 444 5555 and all combinations thereof.

Comment: And what about 1-333-444-5555? How about 333-444-5555x1234?

Answer (score 1):

Since you're using `preg_match()`, I'll assume you're using PHP.  For phone numbers, because of their variability even in N.Am. (11,10 or 7 digits, varying or no separating characters, etc.) you may find a function like this easier to deal with than a regex:

```
function validphone(&$value) { //test for N.Am. phone number and reformat in standard format
    $valid=false;
    $area=NULL;
    $working=preg_replace('/\D/', '', $value); //only numbers left, no preceding zeros
    switch (strlen($working)) { //cases fall through from 11 to 7
        case 11: //e.g. 19024355764
            $working=stristr($working,'1'); //trims off 1st 1
        case 10: //e.g. 9024355764
            $area=substr($working,0,-7);
            $working=substr($working,3); //trims off 1st 3
        case 7: //e.g. 4355764
            $value=implode('-',array($area,substr($working,0,-4),substr($working,-4)));
            $valid=true;
            break;
        default:
            $valid=false;
            break;
    }
    return $valid;

}
```

ETA your questions in the comments:

You have a string that should be a phone number

```
$phonish='blahblah#._foo(123)4567890 ixlybob';
if(validphone($phonish)){ //function checks if $phonish is valid & reformats it in a standard way
  //do something with $phonish, which now equals '123-456-7890'
} else {
  echo 'not a valid phone number';
}
```

The `validphone()` function is most appropriate for shortish strings that are expected to be phone numbers. If you dump an entire page into a string and then feed it to `validphone($mywholepage)`, it will extract **all** the numbers in the string at once. So text with multiple phone numbers will return false and text that happens to have 11,10 or 7 digits distributed throughout will return true.

Comment: Still no idea. If i add that to code, how do I return what it gets to a variable

Comment: @Kirk: the function is pass by reference, so the original `$value` is substituted with the reformatted one, if it exists and a boolean is returned so you know if it worked.  Call it like this `if(validphone($phonish)) //do something`.  In terms of how you determine what should be in `$phonish`, it sounds like you are committing the cardinal sin of parsing HTML with regexes. Don't.  There are better and easier options.  Just search SO for HTML and regex- it's one of the most popular questions out there.

Comment: I don't know how to call this function properly. Could you help me?

Answer (score 0):

In the beginning, your searching for optional `+1` and some greedy string. Changing

```
(?:[.-]\s*)?
```

to

```
(?:[.-]\d*?)?
```

should do the trick, but maybe there are even more problems in your regex.